# Question on unique permissions count

Tags: folder, item-level-permissions, unique

I am having a folder with 100 documents. Now I am breaking inheritance on this folder and applying unique permissions on it. Yes, all the documents under this folder will have same permissions as parent folder.

Now question is, if I apply unique permissions on a folder, it will treat as one unique permission or 101 unique permissions (since folder contains 100 documents)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be treated as one unique permission.
Setting folder permissions is a best practice, consider this article - [Best practices for using fine-grained permissions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/best-practices-for-using-fine-grained-permissions-in-sharepoint-server#too-many-scopes-in-a-list):

> Only set unique scopes on parent objects such as folders.

If you want to learn technical things, limitation and best practices regarding permissions even more deeply, consider also [Best practices for using fine-grained permissions (SharePoint Products and Technologies) White Paper](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=201596). It's old reading, however nothing changed drastically regarding permissions in SharePoint